# PHP: Echo random value from array depending on another previous value, also random

Tags: php, arrays, random

I need to echo a series of four strings depending on a previous result of a array_rand(). I have this, so far:

```
<?php

$titles = array('title1','title2','title3','title4');

$title1_words = array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7');
$title2_words = array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7');
$title3_words = array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7');
$title4_words = array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7');

$rand_title = array_rand($titles, 1);
echo $rand_title . "<br>";


//print 4 random words from one group
$rand_words = array_rand($title1_words, 4);
echo $title1_words[$rand_words[0]] . "<br>";
echo $title1_words[$rand_words[1]] . "<br>";
echo $title1_words[$rand_words[2]] . "<br>";
echo $title1_words[$rand_words[3]] . "<br>";

?>
```

I need the output to be something like:

"Title 2

word2, word4, word5, word7", where those words are actually related to the main title.

(Words vary from group to group. I just used the same names to make it easier to understand.)

It is expected to echo different values everytime I refresh the page.

// Edit for further explanation //

When it refresh, it should echo another Title and another set of 4 words related to that title.

P.S.: Srsly, why the down votes? At least explain it.

Comment: Store your data differently and the problem almost solves itself: `$data = ['title1' => ['word1', ...], ...]`.

Comment: If you have "numbered" variable names, then you can generally make your life easier using a decent array... rebuild your title words array as `$title_words = array(
    'title1' => array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7'),
    'title2' => array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7'),
    'title3' => ('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7'),
    'title4' => array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7'),
);`

Comment: And the problem is...?  I just copy-pasted your code to my PHP, it works.  Purists will suggest modifications (like multi-dimensional array), but it does output what you want.

Comment: @Nic suggesting a multidimensional array is not a "purist" suggestion, it's a suggestion for how to solve the problem.

Comment: Just pointing out that his code does work.  A newbie approach for sure.

Comment: @Nic I would argue that the OP's code does _not_ work in the way the OP wants it to. The statement _"It is expected to echo different values everytime I refresh the page"_ suggests that the OP want this to be automatic, not hard coded as the example code.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker. I'm not sure though how to print it the way I needed.

Comment: @Hugo: so you want to modify the output only?  Play with your prints, remove the <br>, ...  If you want to have the results printed 4 times, use a for loop to execute 4 times.

Comment: `echo $rand_title . "<br>";` is wrong. it has to be `echo $titles[$rand_title] . "<br>";`. But your code SHOULD print different values everytime you reload it. So where do you struggle?

Comment: @JoshuaK the random word values vary depending on the previous title generated, which is also an array.

Comment: Ok. That was the point I overread / didn't got.

Comment: @JoshuaK For title1 => on set of words
For title 2 => Another set of words
And so on. I need to generate a different title and a set of 4 words within it.

Comment: Something like [this](https://3v4l.org/g1HvD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the best way to deal with this issue would be to store your words in a two-dimensional array, as such :

```
$words = array(
    'title1' => array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7')),
    'title2' => array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7')),
    'title3' => array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7')),
    'title4' => array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7')),
);
```

And then use `$words[$titles[$rand_title]]` as your words subarray.

However, if you can't (or absolutely don't want to) use two-dimensional arrays, you could always use **[variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)** :

```
<?php

$titles = array('title1','title2','title3','title4');

$title1_words = array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7');
$title2_words = array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7');
$title3_words = array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7');
$title4_words = array('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5','word6','word7');

$rand_title = array_rand($titles, 1);
echo $rand_title . "<br>";

$title = $titles[$rand_title]; // should be title2, for instance
$words_array = ${$title . '_words'}; // should be $title2_words, for instance

$rand_words = array_rand($words_array, 4);
echo $words_array[$rand_words[0]] . "<br>";
echo $words_array[$rand_words[1]] . "<br>";
echo $words_array[$rand_words[2]] . "<br>";
echo $words_array[$rand_words[3]] . "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot @roberto06.
The only change necessary - but that was on me - was replacing echo $rand_title  by echo $titles[$rand_title]